# Codeigniter callbacks affecting required validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3.1.1. I am new to codeigniter and i have ran into a problem i can get figured out. My callback functions seem to affect the required validation in that the required rule seems to be skipped and the callback function gets executed even when the field is empty. Here's my code

```
$validate_data = array(

        array(

            'field' => 'pages',
            'label' => 'No of pages',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|integer|callback_regex_pages'
            )
  );

  $this->form_validation->set_rules($validate_data);
  $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">','</p>');
```

My callback function

```
   public function regex_pages(){

if(!preg_match('/^\d(\d)?(\d)?$/',$this->input->post('pages'))){

    $this->form_validation->set_message('regex_pages', 'The {field} is not valid!');

    return false;

    }else{

    return true;

    }
   }//end method regex_pages
```

This is just one of my many callbacks that behave this way. If I remove the callback rule, the required rule gets executed

This is my output below

[image: My output]

Comment: What is the input, show sample of it

Comment: I believe that `$this->form_validation->run()` will test all the rules whether or not any one of them returns false. That is to say, even if the required rule returns false that won't stop regex_pages from being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to extend your form validation library by making a new library called "MY_form_validation" which will extend "CI_form_validation" and save it in "libraries" folder; After this, put your all callback functions in MY_form_validation and in this way, you will have global available your callbacks, but keep in mind, you no need to set rule with prefix "callback".
Here is an example:

```
$validate_data = array(

    array(

        'field' => 'pages',
        'label' => 'No of pages',
        'rules' => 'trim|required|integer|regex_pages'
        )
```

);

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($validate_data);
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">','</p>');
```

So in MY_form_validation you will make the function

```
public function regex_pages($value_to_be_validated){

if(!preg_match('/^\d(\d)?(\d)?$/',$value_to_be_validated)){

$this->set_message('regex_pages', 'The {field} is not valid!');

return false;

}else{

return true;

}
```

Comment: That seemed to to be a solution but not quite form rules that require access to the database such as checking if an email address exists because i cannot load my model class or use `$this->db`

Comment: Oh I figured it out used ` $this->CI->load->database();`

Comment: You can load your database or anything you want by calling the function get_instance(); So, if you do something like $CI = get_instance(); You will call your database by $CI->load->database(); If you want to load a model, you simple type: $CI->load->model('your_name_model'); After this, you will be able to call your model by typing: $CI->your_model_name->your_method();

Answer (score 1):

Set the message no matter if the field's value is valid or not.

```
 public function regex_pages($value){

   //set message anyway
   $this->form_validation->set_message('regex_pages', 'The {field} is not valid!');

   //the rule will be available for any field, not just for pages
   return (bool) preg_match('/^\d(\d)?(\d)?$/',$value);

}
```

You also can use the Codeigniter regex_match rule. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form%20validation#CI_Form_validation

```
'rules' => 'trim|required|integer|regex_match[//]'
```